# Postgres Import by CSV gives a 42601 error

Tags: postgresql

Good day.
I am new to postgres. There is this youtube tutorial on how to import data from csv to table but I cant seem to add it.

```
COPY public."table_name" FROM 'somewhere\import1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

This was the code that he added but it does not work for me. I tried to copy char by char.

This gives me error

`LINE 3: COPY public."table_name`

```
SQL state: 42601
Character: 58
```

This is my DB structure if it matters:

```
dbname
  Schemas
    public
      ..
      ..
      table_name
```

Comment: Please share the table schema & a sample of what the file looks like including the header a few rows of data should suffice. Otherwise its very difficult for someone to guess why you are facing this issue and how to fix it.

Comment: If COPY was line 3, what was in lines 1 and 2?